# Jquery ajax url in controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-2

Can some body explain How  actually jquery ajax method url points to a controller action?I mean the machinery behind the technology.For example

```
 $("#Location").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Vacancy/AutoCompleteLocations',
                data: request,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "GET",
                minLength: 2,
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { label: item.REF_DESC, value: item.REF_DESC, id: item.REF_ID }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#hdLocationId").val(ui.item.id);
        }
    });
```

I want to know how  url: '/Vacancy/AutoCompleteLocations' points the particular action means the machinery.

Comment: If you mean how the computer find the action from `url:'/Vacancy/AutoCompleteLocations'`,see http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/system.web.routing.route

Answer (score 2):

An [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) application has something called a *Route Table*. The *Route Table* maps particular URLs to particular controllers. An application has one and only one *Route Table*. This *Route Table* is setup in the [global-asax](/questions/tagged/global-asax) file. In case you don't have *Route Table*, application will always give 404 error.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new 
        { 
             controller = "Home", 
             action     = "Index", 
             id         =  UrlParameter.Optional 
        } // Parameter defaults
    );

}
```

**Case -1**. *Consider a case when you have Area in your application. But, you did not mention the Area name in the URL. Example* **localhost/ControllerName/ActionName**. *If you Pay attention to the URL, there is no Area Name. Also there is no such Controler in the Root Controller Directory. This Controller exists in the Area. Let's say you have following Area in your application.*

[image: Area]

Now you type the url : **localhost/Test/Index** and hit enter. Now the question is what is happening in background?

Let's added a Reference of **[RoureDebugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/13/routedebugger-2.aspx)**. You can get the Dll from this location. Then I added a line of code in my [global-asax](/questions/tagged/global-asax) file under *Application_Start* Handler.

```
RouteDebug.RouteDebugger.RewriteRoutesForTesting(RouteTable.Routes);
```

When I execute the application. This shows me following output, instead of Index page response.

[image: RouteDebugging]

*If you pay attention to the above screenshot, Default Route is enabled which is present in the [global-asax](/questions/tagged/global-asax) file. It's because default Url without constraint will locate the Controller anywhere in the application. But the View is neither present in the Root Folder View's Directory nor present in the Shared Folder View's Directory. Finally you will get 404 error.*

**How can I get rid of this issue ?**

I faced the similar issue in the past and found the corrective action. below is the new version of default Route in [global-asax](/questions/tagged/global-asax) file.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    var route = routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new 
        { 
            controller = "Home", 
            action     = "Index", 
            id         = UrlParameter.Optional 
        }, // Parameter defaults
        new[] { "MvcApplication1.Controllers" }
    );
    route.DataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = false;
}
```

*In the above code I added Namespace in the constraint and `route.DataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = false;` in the route. After doing this and using the above mentioned URL, Controller Action Method will never be executed because Area Name is not present in the Controller.*

Also I figured out one more important information regarding the DataTokens when the Url does not contains the Area Name and Default Route does not contain the NameSpace information. below is the screenshot.

[image: DataToken Without NameSpace]

*The Data Token information will not be available when the Url does not contains the Area Name and Default Route does not contain the NameSpace information.*

Now, after adding the NameSpace and adding the Area Name in the Url as per the revised Default Route. We will get the DataToken Information as shown below in the screen shot.

[image: Data Token with NameSpace]

Below is the `RouteData` Output after adding the Area Name in the Url

[image: Route Debugging]

As you can see the Area Route is enabled now.

Hope this will help you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET MVC, the URL are of the following form

```
http://HostName/ControllerName/ActionName/Id
```

you can validate it by looking at the routes defined in `Application_Start`

So for your URL `/Vacancy/AutoCompleteLocations` (which is a relative URL means it will be appended next to the URL in your browser's address bar), Vacancy is the name of the Controller (try and find `VacancyController.cs` in Controllers folder) and `AutoCompleteLocations` is the name of the Action (a function in VacancyController.cs file)

The Id part is usually optional.

Answer (score 0):

First of all

```
$("#Location").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'URL.Action("ActionName","ControllerName")',
            data: request,
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            minLength: 2,
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return { label: item.REF_DESC, value: item.REF_DESC, id: item.REF_ID }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#hdLocationId").val(ui.item.id);
    }
});
```

We are define route either in Global.asax or route table.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

This is define First one is Controller and another is action Name.

Answer (score 0):

It's concern of [Routing system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that is very constomizable.

> A route is a URL pattern that is mapped to a handler. The handler can
> be a physical file, such as an .aspx file in a Web Forms application.
> A handler can also be a class that processes the request, such as a
> controller in an MVC application. To define a route, you create an
> instance of the Route class by specifying the URL pattern, the
> handler, and optionally a name for the route.

By default in MVC project you have following route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

That says that:

1. In your first segment should be name of controller, if not - by default it will be Home;
2. In your second segment should be name of controller action, if no - by default it will be Index.
3. And the last segment is id, but it's optional.

So id you have default route and url '/Vacancy/AutoCompleteLocations' then you will call controller Vacancy and action AutoCompleteLocation.